# Problem when I export from Blender in FBX, no texture is exported

Tags: texturing, export, unreal-engine

I have been exporting in Blender and wanting to practice with 3D models that I have textured well and I have assigned to the models, but when I export these never carry the texture or color.

Only pure white remains in the 3D preview and in the model in Unreal Engine, it is not a problem of "Path Mode" or "Embed Textures" because I have them activated to 100% and still happens these.

I do not know what happens and I've tried a lot.[image]
[image]

enter image description here

Comment: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures).